# handler for python HTTPServer that uses threads

Tags: python, webserver, mod-pywebsocket

id like to write a handler for the standalone server coming with pywebsocket (http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket) that uses a thread. 
in the example coming with pywebsocket the handler is just a file with a function:

```
def web_socket_transfer_data(request):
  while True:
    line = request.ws_stream.receive_message()
    if line is None:
      return
    request.ws_stream.send_message(line)
    if line == _GOODBYE_MESSAGE:
      return
```

ive tried to add a thread:

```
class _Stub(threading.Thread): 
def __init__ (self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self._test = 0

def run(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        self._test = self._test + 1
```

but the server crashes without any comment...
so how is this done?

thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone server isn't designed to receive messages non-blocking. From the documentation of the class "MessageReceiver" in [msgutil.py](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/source/browse/trunk/src/mod_pywebsocket/msgutil.py) (at least not when using SSL):

> This class receives messages from the client.
>
> ```
> This class provides three ways to receive messages: blocking,
> non-blocking, and via callback. Callback has the highest precedence.
>
> Note: This class should not be used with the standalone server for wss
> because pyOpenSSL used by the server raises a fatal error if the socket
> is accessed from multiple threads.
> ```